# Mixed conditional clause type 1-3

Tags: differences, modal-verbs, conditionals, esl

I came across the following conditional clause while studying a grammar book published by Oxford:

"If you know London so well, you shouldn't have got so hopelessly lost."

The writer of the book has only briefly mentioned that this is a mixed conditional clause (type 1-3) without giving any further explanation in what situation it can be used. I'm already familiar with two other types of mixed conditional clauses (type 2-3 and type 3-2) and have no problem understanding them but this one is causing me some trouble. I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Which typology are you referring to? Has [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) finally released its definitive numerology for mixed conditional clauses?

Comment: A mixed conditional clause of types 1 and 3.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said. Is there a list of types and subtypes somewhere? Or tests to distinguish the various types? Or does one award numbers on some other basis? For that matter, "mixed conditional" doesn't mean much  without unmixed conditionals and mixed non-conditionals to contrast with. All of which are left undefineds. In short, we don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: I've no real interest in "type 1/2/3 conditional" categorisations in the first place, but *semantically* OP's usage seems barely "conditional" at all to me. It looks more like just another way of saying *"**Since** you [claim to] know London so well, you shouldn't have got so hopelessly lost."*

Comment: No. There is no list I can offer and this is the only type 1-3 conditional clause that I have ever seen. You may like to know the book is written by John Eastwood in 2004 named "Oxford Learner's Grammar", page 348. Anyway, what I need to know is when such a conditional clause is used by a native English speaker? Can you picture such a situation?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your putting my sentence another way seems reasonable and meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: @M.N: Oh. I hadn't realised you were asking for help in *understanding* the example. I thought were just asking what *conditional "type number"* it was. Strictly speaking I suspect that if we *insist* on using ***if***, the intended sense should probably be expressed by *"If you **knew** London so/as well [as you claim], ...* I don't know if that helps you any more. But I would strongly urge you to consider using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for any future questions - you'll probably get better answers more targeted to non-native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your advice. Sure. In fact, in that grammar book it was mentioned that it is a mix of type 1 and type 3. However, what I was trying to find out by asking this question here was to know "in what situation" a native English speaker uses such a clause?

Comment: Isn't it `gotten` instead of `got`?

Comment: Well, in American English it could be replaced by "gotten".

Comment: Don't take too much notice of my rep here on ELU. Mostly it just reflects the fact that I've been here quite a while, and I have too much time on my hands, rather than in-depth knowledge of formal grammar. For your "in what situation" query you really need someone like [StoneyB](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) over on ELL (he knows lots of the "formal" stuff). My guess is your example here is a highly informal kind of "bastardised subjunctive" arrived at by mangling/pruning something like *"If you **would have known** London so well [as you claim],..."*. But what do I know?

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 5):

I urge you stoutly to abjure the Trinity. The  *n<sup>th</sup>-conditional* framework is a pedagogic device which has almost nothing to do with how conditional constructions are actually used.

The sort of conditional you instance is categorized by Declerck and Reed<sup>†</sup>  as an *indirect inferential* of a sort in which

> The verb form of the Q-clause represents Q as counterfactual (=contrary to fact, incompatible with the actual world), so that P, whose form does not normally express counterfactuality, is also interpreted as counterfactual:
> [...]
>
> > (74) b. If (as you say) he really fought in Vietnam for three years, he would {know / have known} a lot about warfare.
>
> [...]
> The counterfactuality of Q—or, more correctly, the speaker’s assumption of the counterfactuality of Q—is signalled by the use of the conditional tense or conditional perfect in the Q-clause. The fact that Q (whether [+q] or [-q]) is thus represented as false in the actual world forces the hearer to infer that P (which leads to Q) must also be counterfactual, although its verb form does not represent it as such: for the sake of the argument, the speaker purports to represent P as ‘closed’ (-assumed to be true, as is claimed or suggested in the previous context), but then she makes it clear that this interpretation must be reconsidered.

*N<sup>th</sup>-conditionals*, as they are typically taught, are *actualization conditionals*, “If P **happens**, Q **happens**”: actualization of P causes or triggers the actualization of Q, or at least provides a relevant occasion for the utterance of Q. These conditionals require a sequence of eventualities.

But inferential conditionals present virtually no constraint on the tenses and modes of the verbs. Inferential conditionals are not concerned with the actualization of eventualities but with the truth of propositions: (“If P **is true**, Q **is true**”). A proposition may be cast in any tense or mode, but the inference from one proposition to another is always present-tense, although that is rarely made explicit.

---

<sup>†</sup> *Conditionals: A Comprehensive Empirical Analysis*, 2001, 3.6.2, 44-45. The authors’ terminology rests on the traditional conditional template “If P, Q”; they employ *P-clause* for the condition (*IF*) clause and *Q-clause* for the consequence (*THEN*) clause. Lower-case abbreviations [p], [q] represent the propositions expressed in the clauses P and Q, with '+' and '-' representing positive and negative assertions.

Comment: Well said, sir! For your further pleasure: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: @tchrist I'm very fond of this article. Note that it repeatedly alludes to Maule's article from 21 (now 27) years earlier!